# how to save emoji character Telegram to table MySql?

Tags: mysql, telegram-bot

I have a MySql Database.
Save message of Telegram to Table.

message have `Emoji` icon. it's saved ???.
I change Type of Database to `utf8mb4_persian_ci`,and The Table to `utf8mb4_persian_ci` too.

But still ???? it shows.

What do I do?

Comment: Try executing “SET NAMES utf8mb4;”

You can also refer to the list of Unicode emoji characters to ensure the Unicode is correct. Check here >> unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: is it only the emojis that are shown in "???" or the whole message ?
does it show correctly when there are no emojis ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emoticons are generally managed as unicode characters, in telegram i think is same (check this).
So, if these are unicode characters, you can convert it in hex entities and then save it.

In PHP i use this function:

```
preg_replace_callback('/[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', function ($match) {
    list($utf8) = $match;
    $binary = mb_convert_encoding($utf8, 'UTF-32BE', 'UTF-8');
    $entity = vsprintf('&#x%x;', unpack('N', $binary));
    return $entity;
}, $your_text_here);
```

Comment: it's genarate &#x646;&#x648;&#x639; &#x62a;&#x628;&#x644;&#x6cc;&#x63a; &#x631;&#x648; &#x627;&#x632; &#x628;&#x6cc;&#x646; &#x6af;&#x632;&#x6cc;&#x646;&#x647; &#x647;&#x627;&#x6cc; &#x632;&#x6cc;&#x631; &#x1f447; &#x627;&#x646;&#x62a;&#x62e;&#x627;&#x628; &#x6a9;&#x646;&#x6cc;&#x62f;

Comment: Simply put this text in your page, your browser will do the work for you, or use `html_entity_decode($text_here)` :D